# r delete with a condition data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table, I want to delete the "id" which have identical values on the variable "switch_f".

[image]

I wish this exit

[image]

Comment: Downvotes because data should be shared in reproducible form not as images.

Comment: ok sorry, for the next publication I will make a reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DT[, if (uniqueN(Switch_f) == 1L) NULL else .SD, by = id]
# There are many other options, including:
DT[DT[, if (uniqueN(Switch_f) > 1L) .I, by = id]$V1]
DT[DT[, uniqueN(Switch_f) > 1L, by = id][(V1), !"V1"], on = "id"]
```

Reproducible data (please provide yourself next time):

```
DT <- data.table(
  id = rep(1L:7L, c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L)),
  Switch_f = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L),
  sex = rep(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), c(7L, 3L, 3L, 5L))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `subset` + `ave` like below

```
subset(df,as.logical(ave(Switch_f,id,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))>1)))
```

which reserves the groups has more than one unique `Switch_f` values